# How to cut a cube in half

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I've had difficulty trying to cut a cube in half. I tried the knife tool at first, but that didn't work. I also tried using the loop cut too, but it just extrudes. I'd like to be able break it off into two entirely separate objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is fairly simple, but it does utilize the obscure *Rip* tool (<kbd>V</kbd>). Here are the steps:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*.
2. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and move the cursor around until the pink suggested loop cut is dividing the cube in half in the manner that you want it to (*X*, *Y*, or *Z*).
3. <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>, then immediately <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to add the loop to the actual mesh. Make sure it remains selected; nothing else should be selected.
4. Key <kbd>V</kbd> to rip the vertices (opposite of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> / <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*) and once again immediately <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>. You should now have two identical copies of the loop cut that you previously added in the same place and one of them selected.
5. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the rest of one half of the cube.
6. Key <kbd>P</kbd> to open the *Separate* menu and select *By Selection*.
7. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*. You should now have two identical halves of a cube.

*The Procedure:*

[image]

**Edit (Optional Steps 6.5, 8, 9, and 10):**

6.5. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select the loop cut on the remaining half of the cube and key <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face.

8. Select the other cuboid half and <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*.

9. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select the loop cut on the remaining half of the cube and key <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face.

10. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.

*Steps 6.5-10:*

[image]

Comment: You actually don't need to use the Rib tool, seperating into different objects will automatically split the edges.

Comment: @Ezra Good idea!